# Can an Adapter be used on a layout that is being dynamically built in code?

Tags: android, layout, user-interface, adapter

I have an SQL database that I am dynamically adding rows and columns to.

I want to display the data in the SQL database onto a ListView of LinearLayouts, but since the rows and columns are growing and shrinking dynamically, I am going to need to build the layout dynamically in my code.

Is there a way to use a SimpleCursorAdapter to map the data into my layout? Or can the SimpleCursorAdapter only be used on statically defined XML layouts?

Comment: Rows would correspond to to each item, so that's no problem. Question... is there a maximum number of columns? View visibility (View.GONE) could be useful with something like this. Building a layout programmatically is a pain... always favor XML if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an SQL database that I am dynamically adding rows and columns to.

Um, OK.

> I want to display the data in the SQL database onto a ListView of LinearLayouts

Unless you have limits on the number of columns, this may be difficult.

> Is there a way to use a SimpleCursorAdapter to map the data into my layout?

Only if there is a reasonable maximum number of columns. In that case, as @Maximus suggests, you can hide unused columns using `View.GONE`. Otherwise, you are better served using `CursorAdapter` and overriding `newView()` and `bindView()` accordingly.